# Javascript selecting data from div or span

Tags: javascript, html

I'm in the process of learning javascript, I'm trying to find useful ways of obtaining data, that is already displayed on a page (lets say its wrapped up in a div or a span), what would be the best way to go about collecting that data and storing in javascript?

Is there any good reading materials to help get started with javascript?

Comment: Use [getElementById](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp)

Comment: Indeed that would be the standard way

Comment: Cannot be answered without knowing the DOM structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can read up about the **document object** [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document),

> Each web page loaded in the browser has its own document object. The Document interface serves as an entry point into the web page's content (the DOM tree, including elements such as  and ) and provides functionality which is global to the document (such as obtaining the page's URL and creating new elements in the document)

and learn about its methods, such as 'getElementById', [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById).